# Why does this component not appear when `*ngIf` is true?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to make a popup appear when user hovers over a given image `<img>`.

My popup is a component called `<cxui-popover>` which can be seen below.

I used the `(mouseenter) (mouseleave)` events to activate 2 functions on mouse hover. These functions set the value of `celldata.showPopOverForConnectivity` to true/false. When set to true, it should show the `<cxui-popover>` template below. However, on hover over, it doesn't show anything. I put a console log inside my `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function and confirmed that this property was indeed set to true whenever my mouse was over the image.

As I am quite new to Angular, I'm unsure if there's something about templates which I'm not aware of causing this to happen. Thanks.

Main component

```
<ng-template #deviceTemplate let-celldata="celldata">
    <span class="half-margin-right" *ngIf="celldata">
        <img 
            alt=" Asset Icon" i18n-alt  
            class="icon-asset"
            [ngClass]="{ 'grayscale': celldata.connectivity === 'NOT_CONNECTED' }"
            attr.data-auto-id="DeviceIcon-{{ celldata?.productType }}"
            [src]="celldata?.category?.toLowerCase() === categories.Amp ? celldata : assetProductIcon"
            (mouseenter)="onHoveringTheCheckIcon(celldata, 'connectivity')"
            (mouseleave)="onClose2(celldata)"
        >
        <cxui-popover *ngIf="celldata?.showPopOverForConnectivity"
                    class="popover-connectivity-assets"
                    [placement]="bottom"
                    [height]="90"
                    (onClose)="onClose2(celldata)"
                    >
            <div *ngIf="celldata?.connectivity?.toUpperCase() === 'CONNECTED'" class="qtr-margin-left qtr-margin-right text-small">
                <div  i18n>Asset connected.</div>
                <div  i18n>This asset was collected from controllers etc.</div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="celldata?.connectivity?.toUpperCase() === 'NOT_CONNECTED'" class="qtr-margin-left qtr-margin-right text-small">
                <div  i18n>Asset not connected.</div>
                <div  i18n>This asset was not collected from etc.</div>
            </div>
        </cxui-popover>
    </span>
</ng-template>
```

Popover.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cxui-popover',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PopoverComponent{
  @Input() size: PopoverSize = PopoverSize.Default;
  @Input() placement = PopoverPlacement.Bottom;
  @Input() height = 0;
  @Input() showCloseButton = false;
  @Output() readonly closed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  closePopover() {
    this.closed.emit();
  }
}
```

Popover.component.html

```
<ng-template>
  <div
    class="cx-popover active"
    [class.cx-popover--small]="size === 'SMALL'"
    [class.cx-popover--large]="size === 'LARGE'"
    role="tooltip"
  >
    <button
      *ngIf="showCloseButton"
      class="close"
      type="button"
      aria-label="Close Popover"
      data-testid="closeButton"
      (click)="closePopover()"
    >
      <span
        class="close-icon"
        aria-hidden="true"
      ></span>
    </button>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Try to debug by adding ` {{ celldata?.showPopOverForConnectivity }}` on top of `<cxui-popover *ngIf="celldata?.showPopOverForConnectivity"` and see if it goes from `true` to `false`.

Comment: @AliF50 It is always true :/

Comment: So that's the issue, you have to find out why it is always true in the HTML.

Comment: I mean, it is true when I hover over, as it should be.